Where is the Rogachover's piece about infinity vis-a-vis Sefiras HaOmer?
Years ago I'd heard a shiur about the Rogachover's answer to a kashya in Sefiras HaOmer involving infinity; that if something starts at one point and then extends on infinitely from there, it doesn't really have a start point and would thus be considered infinite in both directions -- or something like that. Can anyone point me to this piece, please? (Is it in Tzafnas Paneach on the Yad?)

I am aware of this concept, more or less, brought up by the Tzemach Tzedek, if you are interested. FYI
